# Using CSS to nudge my text over by 10px

Tags: css, positioning

I have a div that is 235px wide by 30px high and at the moment my text sits flush to the left inside of the div.

I want to nudge my text to the right by 10px so that it is just of the "wall" of the div but I can't seem to achieve this properly using padding and margins.

Here is my code so far :

```
.menutop {
    height:30px;
    width:235px;
    background-color:rgb(221,221,221);
    color:#666;
    line-height:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#999;
}
```

When ever I add `padding`/`padding:left` or `margin`/`margin:left` it seems to move the div as well as the text inside.

What is the easiest way to achieve what I am after?

Example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjvv7/).

Comment: You could just use `text-indent` like so: http://jsfiddle.net/sjvv7/1/

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue: I've added a 10px `padding-left` and it seems to work right: http://jsfiddle.net/sjvv7/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use:

```
padding-left:10px;
```

instead of `padding:left`

This will increase the width of your `div` by 10px so you might want to reduce that by 10px. The rendered width of a box type element is equal to the sum of its width, left/right border and left/right padding (left/right margin comes into play as well).

Or you can use:

```
text-indent:10px;
```

Note that if the text spans more than one line, `text-indent` will only indent the first line.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `padding-left`. But OMG I tried this and it didn't work earlier! haha, bloody CSS. Thanks anyway @tomsullivan1989

Comment: Well, answer is fine, but just a note, `text-indent` is good for a single, multiple word..but will be a bad choice if the text goes upto 2 lines

Comment: oooh no, actually. It's doing what it did before, it's also adding 10px to the width of the div too

Comment: Ah! but text-indent works perfect as I'm only having one line

Comment: @Adsy padding adds extra space to the element, if you want, you can use `text-indent` else wrap the word using a `span`, assign `display block` to `span` and use `margin` or `padding left`

Comment: Thanks both for your answers!

Comment: @Adsy or you can also take a look at `box-sizing` property which will count the padding inside instead of counting it outside

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thank you, I've never heard of `box-sizing` before